# Combinatorics(bijection or not and find the inverse)

Tags: combinatorics

Show that the function f : R − {−1} → R − {−2} defined by
f(x) = (3 − 4x)/(2x + 2)
is a bijection. Find its inverse.

I know that it is a bijection. It is one to one, since no two elements are mapped in the same event (no value of y, which has 2 x values). It is onto, since for every f(x) there is an x.

For the inverse, I'm not sure how to do it.

Please check over my work and help me find the inverse. I am also a little bit confused as to what the domain is supposed to mean.

Comment: What work are we supposed to check over? For instance, how do you know that this function is injective?

Comment: its a bijection, since it says to find its inverse. Inverse is only possible if its a bijection

Comment: When I said check over my work I meant to check over my explanation. And then help me find the inverse

Comment: So, say I don't trust the author of your textbook. Why is this function bijective?

Comment: because it is onto and one-to-one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: To find the inverse, let $x=\frac{3-4y}{2y+2}$ and solve for $y$.

The domain places restrictions on the possible values  of the function. For instance, try plugging in $x=-1$ and see what output it gives you.

Comment: is my explanation for bijection correct?

Comment: To show it is one to one, you need to show that if $x_1 \neq x_0$ for some $x_0, x_1$ in your domain then $f(x_0) \neq f(x_1)$. To show it is onto, you need to show that for every $b$ in the range, there is some $a$ in the domain such that $f(a)=b$. Set up an equation and solve for the $a$ would be for some arbitrary $b$.

Comment: Can you explain how to prove for onto pls? I didnt fully understand.

Comment: If you've already found the inverse, just show that it is the inverse for $f$ by plugging it into $f$ i.e. $f(f^-1(x))$ and if it equals $x$ then it is in fact the inverse and is therefore bijective.